# Create table ordering based on chaining rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table within SQL Server.

We are trying to create a `Row_ID` / ordering based on the `Network_Route_ID`.

`Route_id` A (Object1) will never connect to anything within the table and is anchored as row 1.

Object1 will always link to object2 (Via B), object2 will link to object3 (Via C) and so on...

| Object_ID | Network_Route_ID | Row_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Object1 | A | 1 |
| Object1 | B | - |
| Object2 | C | - |
| Object3 | D | - |
| Object2 | B | - |
| Object3 | C | - |

Desired output:

| Object_ID | Network_Route_ID | Row_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Object1 | A | 1 |
| Object1 | B | 2 |
| Object2 | B | 3 |
| Object2 | C | 4 |
| Object3 | C | 5 |
| Object3 | D | 6 |

What I have tried so far:

```
Select *  
from #table as main
left join #table as oppo on (main.Network_Route_ID = oppo.Network_Route_ID ) 
                         and (main.Object_ID <> oppo.Object_ID)
```

As I am not well versed in CTEs. The above would act as a helper column to feed into a `lag()` but I can't see plausible partition by and order by statements. The dataset can be one to many.

Comment: Where is the information of the hierarchy between your objects stored?

Comment: @ThomA, you're probably supposed to figure it out from the route column thingy. I have no idea how, but i have a feeling OP doesn't either

Comment: @ThomA Hi. Its a single dataset which makes this tricky as there is no other lookup tables bar knowing row 1. If we consider it a route broken up into multiple sections, we are trying to get from A > D, hence the ordering or a route ID. TNX

Comment: yes correct @siggemannen, you are correct.

Comment: So what is the logic. Start at A, and then join A to A+1 (B) on the same server, then join B to B on a different server, then join B to B+1(C) on the same server, then join C to t C on a different6 server, etc, etc? Can you get to Z? If so, what is Z+1?

Comment: The fact that you have a letter for your Network_Route_ID is making this way harder than it needs to be. Whenever you find yourself with a query that is this difficult to figure out it is almost always a sign that the database design is the root of the problem. Your data is so obfuscated here it is hard to follow but I suspect the design is why this is so hard.

Comment: So for any given `Object_Id` there is a `Min( Network_Route_Id )` that relates it to the next lower `Object_Id` and a `Max( Network_Route_Id )` that relates it to the next higher `Object_Id`, right? There are special cases for the first (`'Object1'`) and last since the relations end at those points. Since `Network_Route_Id` is _always_ a single letter then `Min` and `Max` will order them correctly. If there is more than one digit in `Object_Id` then some additional work is involved to get the order right.

Comment: Well I *have* an answer, but it's based on my [guessed logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77082256/create-table-ordering-based-on-chaining-rows#comment135887843_77082256), and I'm not a fan of posting guesses...

Comment: @ThomA Not sure what everyone is complaining about, seems a fairly simple double-join in a rCTE https://dbfiddle.uk/0U696ruA then unpivot on the end

Comment: @Charlieface - Thank you very much. This provided the routing we needed. This data was from imports via excel and created manual by a forestry team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need a double join in a recursive CTE, in order to join the first and second row of each group.

Then you unpivot at the end.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      t1.Object_ID,
      Network1 = t1.Network_Route_ID,
      Network2 = t2.Network_Route_ID,
      RowId = 2
    FROM YourTable t1
    JOIN YourTable t2
      ON t2.Object_ID = t1.Object_ID
     AND t2.Network_Route_ID <> t1.Network_Route_ID
    WHERE t1.Object_ID = 'Object1'
      AND t1.Network_Route_ID = 'A'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t1.Object_ID,
      t1.Network_Route_ID,
      t2.Network_Route_ID,
      RowId = cte.RowId + 2
    FROM cte
    JOIN YourTable t1
      ON t1.Network_Route_ID = cte.Network2
     AND t1.Object_ID <> cte.Object_ID
    JOIN YourTable t2
      ON t2.Object_ID = t1.Object_ID
     AND t2.Network_Route_ID <> t1.Network_Route_ID
)
SELECT
  cte.Object_ID,
  v.*
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (Network1, RowId - 1),
    (Network2, RowId)
) v(Network_Route_ID, Row_ID);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/0U696ruA)